# How to output multiple custom fields on a WooCommerce hooked function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm using the following bit of code to get data from ACF to the additional info tab on the single product page. Now I need to add multiple of these labels with values. I tried a few things but I cant seem to figure out how to add more in this bit of code. I also need to add ' cm' behind the value that will get pulled because it is a dimension. But the first problem is the most important. Would appreciate!

````php
function yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes($product_attributes, $product){
    $product_attributes['customfield'] = [
        'label' => __('Zithoogte', 'text-domain'),
        'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), '_custom_meta_field1', true),
    ];
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes','yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 10, 2);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - Included if statements on each custom field, checking that the value is not empty

Did you tried using something like (for multiple custom fields):

```
function yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes( $product_attributes, $product ){

    // First custom field
    $value1 = get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), '_custom_meta_field1', true);
    if ( ! empty( $value1 ) ) {  
         $product_attributes['customfield1'] = [
            'label' => __('Zithoogte', 'text-domain'),
            'value' => $value1 . ' cm'
        ];
    }

    // 2nd custom field    
    $value2 = get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), '_custom_meta_field2', true);
    if ( ! empty( $value2 ) ) {  
        $product_attributes['customfield2'] = [
            'label' => __('Label text 2', 'text-domain'),
            'value' => $value2 . ' cm'
        ];
    }

    // 3rd custom field     
    $value3 = get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), '_custom_meta_field3', true);
    if ( ! empty( $value3 ) ) {
        $product_attributes['customfield3'] = [
            'label' => __('Label text 3', 'text-domain'),
            'value' => $value3 . ' cm'
        ];
    }
    
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes','yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 10, 2);
```

It should works.

Comment: It did work thanks! Now one more question, do you also know what to add to make it so if a field was empty, it doesnt return anything? For example when I let the value in ACF which should come to Label text 3 as blank, I dont want the row to show up on the product page. Is that an easy adjustment?